# Print format in python

Tags: python, printing

I have a question just purely try to improve my coding.
Suggest I have a list:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
```

I would like to print a result like below:

```
Path is: 1 --> 2 --> 3
```

My code works just fine:

```
text = ''
for j in range(len(a)):
    text += str(a[j])
    if j < len(a) - 1:
        text = text + ' --> '
print('Path is:', text)
```

I am wondering, is there any better way to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `str.join`:

```
' --> '.join(map(str, a))
```

Or if `a` already only contains strings:

```
' --> '.join(a)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.join()` to create a new string with repetitions of a separator:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
str_a = [str(n) for n in a]
print(" --> ".join(str_a))
```